# Transposing the equation $ y = \frac{x}{1-x} $ to get $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't solve the following equation for $x$. I got my wires crossed

$ y = \frac{x}{1-x} $

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have $$y=\frac{x}{1-x}$$ ,multiplying by $1-x$ we get
$$y-yx=x$$ adding $$yx$$ and we have $$y=x(1+y)$$ dividing by $$1+y\ne 0$$ we obtain
$$x=\frac{y}{1+y}$$

Answer (score 1):

$y=\frac{x}{1-x}$

$y(1-x) = x$

$y - yx = x$

$y = x + xy$

$y = x(1 + y)$

$\frac{y}{(1+y)} = x$

Interchanging two sides,

$x = \frac{y}{(1+y)}$

Comment: If doubt in any step please ask.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$y=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
The numerator and denominator can both be divided by $x$:
$$y=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}-1}$$
Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{x}-1$:
$$y\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)=1$$
Dividing both sides by $y$:
$$\frac{1}{x}-1=\frac{1}{y}$$
Can you take it from here?